# Strip whitespace from jsp output

Tags: jsp, tomcat, whitespace

How can I strip out extra whitespace from jsp pages' output?  Is there a switch I can flip on my web.xml?  Is there a Tomcat specific setting?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

There is a trimWhiteSpaces directive that should accomplish this,

In your JSP:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

Or in the jsp-config section your web.xml (Note that this works starting from servlet specification 2.5.):

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Unfortunately if you have a required space it might also need strip that, so you may need a non-breaking space in some locations.

Comment: Is there a difference in terms of performance between these two options?

Comment: The trimDirectiveWhitespaces is only supported by servlet containers that support JSP 2.1 and after, or in the case or Tomcat, Tomcat 6 (and some versions e.g. Tomcat 6.0.10 don't implement it properly - don't know about the others), there's more information about trimDirectiveWhitespaces here:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jsp_21/

and here

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/trim_spaces_in_your_jsp1

Comment: And in JSP custom .tag files,  use <%@ tag body-content="scriptless" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>.

Comment: Tomcat 7 `web.xml`:    <init-param>
        <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

Comment: I'm running Tomcat 8 and this does not seem to work.  Is it working for anyone?

Comment: I got the same issue while using JSP c:out tag to display a java bean value using tiles. That had leading and trailing whitespaces .
This solution worked correctly , using page directive like this fixed the issue !

Answer (score 28):

If your servletcontainer doesn't support the JSP 2.1 `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` property, then you need to consult its `JspServlet` documentation for any initialization parameters. In for example [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html), you can configure it as well by setting `trimSpaces` init-param to `true` in for `JspServlet` in Tomcat's `/conf/web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

A completely different alternative is the [JTidyFilter](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/filter.html). It not only trims whitespace, but it also *formats* HTML in a correct indentation.

Comment: I have configured by setting trimSpaces init-param to true in /conf/web.xml but the spaces in the generated html are not trimmed.
I am using Tomcat 6.0. Any ideas?

Comment: @ria: Note that you need to understand that this only trims whitespace left by taglibs like JSTL and scriptlets. If you want to trim ALL whitespace from HTML, then head for a different solution. You can find a filter example here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/whitespacefilter.html

Comment: I have just noticed a couple snags with the code from the article b/c things on my site started showing up wrong. I copied the html source and pasted it into the w3 validator to find out that the whitespace filter is occasionally concatenating attributes. For example this... <div onclick="correct()" class="correct"> would turn into this <div onclick="wrong"class="wrong">. Or this <a class="correct"> into this <aclass="wrong">. So by losing the whitespace the close tag for the element becomes invalid. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 5):

The trimDirectiveWhitespaces is only supported by servlet containers that support JSP 2.1 and after, or in the case or Tomcat, Tomcat 6 (and some versions e.g. Tomcat 6.0.10 don't implement it properly - don't know about the others).
There's more information about trimDirectiveWhitespaces here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jsp-21-136414.html

and here

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/trim_spaces_in_your_jsp1

Answer (score 4):

Not directly what you're asking for, but what helps me is putting HTML comment tags in a clever way around my jsp tags, and also putting whitespace inside a servlet tag (<% %>):

```
${"<!--"}
<c:if test="${first}">
    <c:set var="extraClass" value="${extraClass} firstRadio"/>
</c:if>
<c:set var="first" value="${false}"/>
${"-->"}<%

%><input type="radio" id="input1" name="dayChooser" value="Tuesday"/><%
%><label for="input1" class="${extraClass}">Tuesday</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using tags, you can apply there too:

```
<%@ tag description="My Tag" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

And on your jsp:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go one step further and also remove newlines (carriage returns) between the html tags at build time.

E.g. change:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>How are you?</p>
```

into:

```
<p>Hello</p><p>How are you?</p>
```

Do do that, use the `maven-replacer-plugin` and set it up in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>stripNewlines</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${project.build.directory}</basedir>
                <filesToInclude>projectname/WEB-INF/jsp/**/*.jsp</filesToInclude>
                <token>&gt;\s*&lt;</token>
                <value>&gt;&lt;</value>
                <regexFlags>
                    <regexFlag>MULTILINE</regexFlag>
                </regexFlags>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will only modify the JSPs in the build-directory, and not touch the JSPs in your sources.

You might need to adapt the path (`<filesToInclude>`) where your JSPs are located in.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the trim funcion, example

```
fn:trim(string1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/edit your tomcat `catalina.properties` file with

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```

See also: https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Install+Tomcat+7

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit off the actual question, If you want to get rid of the empty lines cause by whatever you did before outputting, you can use

```
out.clearBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

> In web.xml add this servlet this trim param

```
<servlet>
                <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>fork</param-name>
                    <param-value>false</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
                    <param-value>false</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>

            <!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
```