# Removing breaks from jsp

Tags: xml, whitespace, trim

I have a function that transforms XML according to a XSLT.  To test it, I'm using it in a jsp but it's entering a lot of breaks before my output.  It seems to be the breaks I enter when setting variables:

```
<c:set var="blah" value="blah" />
<c:set var="blah2" value="blah2" />
```

That will show two line breaks before the output.  Is there a way to avoid this with XML?  I tried adding trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" but it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip whitespace from jsp output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Tomcat to parse your jsp, you can have a go with:

> ```
> <init-param>
>     <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </init-param>
> ```

In your web.xml. YMMV

Else, I think that JSP 2.1 supports the following:

> 

The last solution is any of this doesn't work is to implement a filter between your JSP rendering and your XSLT computation. A simple filter can be called to trim the spaces around the generated body.