# How to shorten output generated by custom JSP tag?

Tags: java, jsp

Is possible to make output generated by my own JSP tags to be shorter ? For example tag defined as below generate 5 lines instead of 1. Is possible to avoid that (without join all 5 lines into 1 in tag source) ?

```
<%@ tag description="link" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ attribute name="href" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="label" required="false" type="java.lang.String" %>
<a href="<c:url value="${href}"/>">${not empty label ? label : href}</a>
```

not a solution:

```
<%@ tag description="standard input" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %><%@ attribute name="href" required="true" type="java.lang.String" description="address relative to web-app context" %><%@ attribute name="label" required="false" type="java.lang.String" description="link label" %><a href="<c:url value="${href}"/>">${not empty label ? label : href}</a>
```

Comment: This is not an exact dupe of the other question: how does one trim the whitespace output by a custom tag without simply removing all whitespace within the tag? You cannot use <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> within a tag.

Comment: The correct answer is that one can add this in the tag: `<%@ tag trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>`

Comment: should be reopened because the correct answer (see comments) is different from the original question's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can globally configure the JSP parser to trim whitespace which are left by script expressions and tags.

Add this to your webapp's `web.xml` (which has to be Servlet 2.5 compatible!):

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

If you target a Servlet 2.4 container or lower, then you have to edit container's own `web.xml` instead to apply this globally. In Tomcat for example, it's the `/conf/web.xml` file. Search for the `<servlet>` declaration of the `JspServlet` and add the following servlet init parameter inside the `<servlet>` declaration.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: You should bold **Servlet 2.5 compatible**

Comment: @Vlad: Well, 5 years ago I would do. But nowadays, Servlet 2.5 is already out for 5 years... I'd expect everyone to be using that already ;) That exclamation mark is sufficient I think.

Comment: `<trim-directive-whitespaces>` works only for .jsp pages (the same as `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>`), but not work for my own tag generated output. Only `trimSpaces` as init param works at all and get 1-line output of my tag.

Answer (score 18):

As already pointed out by werkshy, to avoid whitespace being generated by directives used in a JSP custom tag,

```
<%@ tag trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

can be used (<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> does not help in this case, as it only seems to apply to directives in the JSP itself and not in the custom tags used by the page).

However, to allow this tag attribute, JSP version 2.1 might need to be specified e.g. using an implicit.tld (as described on https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html or https://forums.oracle.com/thread/742224) which then needs to be placed into directory with the tags. (At least I needed to do that for WebLogic 12c.)

implicit.tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>implicit</short-name>
</taglib>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your JSP:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7.0.19 (Servlet 3.0, JSP 2.2) and `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>` works on jsp page, but not on tag source (`link.tag` in my example). Using that directive on page where my own tag is used doesn't reduce output of tag.

Comment: @marioosh ok, well then maybe you should just trim() your tag's output

Comment: How to do that with tag like in my question ?

Comment: @marioosh sorry I thought you were using a custom tag

Comment: This works for me in Tomcat 6: `<%@ tag trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>` I wish the question could be re-opened to add a real answer.

Comment: @werkshy add your answer to the original (linked) question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output

Comment: Linked question is specifically about a page, this question is specifically about a tag. It seems off-topic to add this to the other question. In my case I was trying to use the output of a custom tag as a url e.g. `<script src="<my:customTag />">`, so whitespace from the tag needed to be trimmed. On a page level I leave in my whitespace.