# Why does struts iterate inserts blank lines in the source code?

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I have this code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>

<% List<String> years = new ArrayList<String>(); %>

<logic:iterate name="ActiviteHolidayForm" property="holidayDays" id="line">
<%
if(!years.contains(line.toString().split("-")[0]))
    years.add(line.toString().split("-")[0]);
%>
</logic:iterate>
```

The problem is that this code inserts a huge number of blank lines in the source code (I suppose equal to the times the code iterates). Is there a way to avoid this? I mention that I have a single line before and after this code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, at first I would have written all this code under one line and tried again. Is that what you meant in "I mention that I have a single line before and after this code." ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip whitespace from jsp output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output)

Comment: Thanks! The return between _id="line">_ and _<%_ and the one between _%>_ and _</logic:iterate>_ seem to cause the problem.

Comment: Bigger question is "why are you doing this in the JSP?"

Comment: @Dave Newton The answer is simple: I don't like how it's done either, but I can't figure out how else to do it, and it works this way. I'm new to JSP and Struts.

Comment: Logic like that should be done in the action, or better still, a service called by the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts is not inserting blank lines; you are inserting blank lines.  Answer this question and you will understand why: "What characters do you have between %> and </logic:iterate>?"

Answer (score 2):

[Summary of New Features in JSP 2.1 Technology](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jsp_21/):

Removing Blank Lines: `TrimWhiteSpace`

Can be done by inserting `<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>` in your `JSP` or by inserting the following part in your web.xml (Servlet 2.5 XSD):

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: I suppose my container doesn't support trimDirectiveWhitespaces because I get this: javax.servlet.ServletException Page directive has invalid attribute: trimDirectiveWhitespaces.