# java loop vertically

Tags: java, html, jsp

Is it possible to loop vertically ? I want to display in JSP by using JSTL foreach . The value is date which is retrieved from database.

Normally looping will be like this :

```
<td>12-12-2011</td>
<td>12-12-2011</td>
<td>12-12-2011</td>
<td>12-12-2011</td>
```

But now I want to display the data like this way :

```
<td>12-12-2011</td> <td>12-12-2011</td> <td>12-12-2011</td> <td>12-12-2011</td>
```

Comment: The browser doesn't care when it's output on the screen. They're all <td> tags..?

Comment: These data are displayed in a table and in a same row.

Comment: Because there's no sense in trying to put your html like that since the browser doesn't care how it is formatted: it will render the elements horizontally.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you reframe your question to *"How to remove whitespace from JSP-generated HTML output?"* This is a way more useful question (which has been asked *and answered* here several times before though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var=".." items=".."><td>${..}</td></c:forEach>
```

But it really doesn't matter whether there are line breaks there or not.

For configuring trimming of whitespaces, check this: [Strip whitespace from jsp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        %>

        <td> 
            <% out.print("12-12-2011"); %>
        </td>

        <%
            }
        %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

try this way. hope it will works..

Comment: I think you didn't understood the concrete question :) Plus, this is also not using JSTL as OP asked, it's following a discouraged way of writing JSPs as they did in prehistory.