# Spaces around spring:message

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

In my spring app, I am using a properties file for strings, and the spring:message tag. I am having trouble putting spaces between the messages though. Here is an example:

```
<p>
    <spring:message code="msg.message1" /> <spring:message code="msg.message2" />
</p>
```

Turns into this:

```
I am message1.I am message 2.
```

I would think that the whitespace I put between the message tags would create a space, but it doesnt. I know I can use &nbsp, but I don't want that all over my markup. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with Spring 3.0.5, unless I use `trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"` in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring. Neither of the two taglibs has control over the output stream when space in between is printed. I can just speculate on two things:

- Is a refresh problem. They are not very usual, but sometimes you have to be sure you have cleaned your project, deleted Tomcat's work directory and so on.
- JSP is configured to trim spaces. This is not the default behavior and it can be configured  in a few ways, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output).

Answer (score 1):

Try a `span` element.  for example

```
<span class="message"><spring:message code="msg.message1"/></span>
<span class="message"><spring:message code="msg.message2"/></span>
```

then if you don't get the spacing you want, add a `.message` (or `span.message`) class that provides the desired spacing.  If you get the spacing you want without adding a class, remove `class="message"` from the spans.

you could use a `&nbsp;`, but my personal preference is to avoid such things (*or forever they will dominate your destiny* :) )

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding `&nbsp;` in your properties file at the end of message value

eg.

```
msg.message1 = I am message1. &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the messages into `<div>` elements?

Use CSS to position them relatively to one another with some border/margin?

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want a space between the messages, you will need `&nbsp;`.