# Can I remove unnecessary newlines/whitespace in my Spring Framework webapp response data?

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

In the response my server gives to the client, I am noticing quite a bit of whitespace and newlines. The response body seems to be sending a newline for every line of parsed JSP. I am just curious if this is a problem someone has already written a bean for? Is this something I even need to worry about?

**Example JSP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<head>
  <title>My Page!</title>
  <% String message = "Hello World!"; %>
</head>
<body>
  <div><%=message%></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example HTML Response:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


<!-- THESE ARE BLANK NEWLINES ... -->



<head>
  <title>My Page!</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  Try:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

More details are available here:  [Strip whitespace from jsp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output)

Answer (score 1):

@aroth has to most correct answer. But it also have consequences, mostly minor.

Alternative is to not have line endings between the tags. e.g:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%><%@page 
import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%><%@page 
import="java.util.Properties"%><%@page 
import="java.util.Map"%><%@page 
import="java.util.HashMap"%><%@page 
import="java.io.IOException"%><head>
  <title>My Page!</title>
  <% String message = "Hello World!"; %>
</head>
<body>
  <div><%=message%></div>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW you can have several imports in a  jsp tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@page import="java.util.Date,java.util.GregorianCalendar,java.util.Properties,java.util.Map,java.util.HashMap,java.io.IOException"%><head>
  <title>My Page!</title>
  <% String message = "Hello World!"; %>
</head>
<body>
  <div><%=message%></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code by calling
the reset method on HttpServletResponse

Comment: But this could reset to much like the http-headers, so be careful using this method.