# Can I make trimDirectiveWhitespace default to true?

Tags: jsp

If I want to use JSPs to create consumable XMLs, it needs to start one line 1, or it will yell loudly. Apparently, some XML parsers can't handle a couple empty lines at the top of the document.

To get around this, I found a handy dandy directive,

```
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

But, I have to add this to every page. It's only a matter of time until someone forgets to put it in one of the pages and pulls their hair out for four days trying to fix their services. Is there a way I can make this default?

Comment: Look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output