# mod-pagespeed on JVM without Apache?

Tags: web-applications, grails, jvm, removing-whitespace

I recently discovered Google's mod-pagespeed for Apache, and its [collapse_whitespace](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-whitespace-collapse) capability.  I'm currently working on a project where a Tomcat instance serves a Grails application.  **Is there any way to recreate the effect's of mod-pagespeed's collapse_whitespace feature, without needing to go through setting up an Apache server?**

Or am I barking up the wrong tree, and this kind of capability is only found in web servers?

There's a discussion at [Strip whitespace from jsp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output) about the trim-directive-whitespaces feature found in JSP-serving platforms but that only affects some extra spaces added by JSP directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Jira open about adding trimDirectiveWhitespaces to GSPs: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7623.

You could implement the "collapse whitespace" to any Java web application (including Grails apps) by using a servlet filter. There might even be such opensource implementations available. These implementations might not be very efficient and can cause problems for apps with a lot of concurrent users.

In Grails 2.3 there will be a major refactoring to the encoding/escaping/xss prevention features of GSPs (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9906).  It would also be possible to build an efficient "collapse whitespace" implementation upon that work. Grails is an opensource project and contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We've found that compressing the output tends to swamp any benefits from collapsing whitespace, so if you can deliver the content with content encoding gzipped. I don't know an easy way to do this if your system doesn't already support it but perhaps a dead simple forward proxy that does nothing but server gzipped content?