# Why Page directive has invalid attribute: "trimDirectiveWhitespaces"?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I have developed one J2EE application in which I have developed one report using jasper reports.I have used Netbeans6.9 IDE and apache tomcat server for deployment. Now when I run my application on local pc Reports works fine i.e excel get generated. But when I deploy war file of my aaplication on JBoss server Report doesnt work it gives this error:

> "Page directive has invalid attribute: trimDirectiveWhitespaces"

.

Answer (score 0):

The `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` attribute was added to the page directive in JSP 2.1
The version of JBoss you are deploying on is probably not JSP 2.1 compliant.

Comment: @user2772285 What Jboss version are you using exactly ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output for more information.