# Spaces in bundle value of spring message

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

I'm using spring mvc and I have a problem with `<spring:message />` tag.
In properties file I have line:
`label.inquiry=Inquiry`
but when I use it in `<spring:message code="label.inquiry" />` the output is:

                                `Inquiry`
One new line character and few spaces. Why and how to resolve this problem?

UPDATE:
I paste an some jsp code

```
<div style="clear:both;margin:5px;">
  <a class="btn mini inquiryFile" href="<c:url value="/download/brokerinquiry.html?ciid=${element.brokerInquiryElement.customerInquiryElement.customerInquiry.id}&sid=${element.brokerInquiryElement.supplier.id}"/>">
    <spring:message htmlEscape="false" code="label.inquiry"/> <i class="icon-download"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the source code of the JSP (with more context: not just the tag), and the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The new line character and the spaces are in your jsp. You could do

```
<div style="clear:both;margin:5px;">
  <a class="btn mini inquiryFile" href="<c:url value="/download/brokerinquiry.html?ciid=${element.brokerInquiryElement.customerInquiryElement.customerInquiry.id}&sid=${element.brokerInquiryElement.supplier.id}"/>"><spring:message htmlEscape="false" code="label.inquiry"/> <i class="icon-download"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can also take a look at [Strip whitespace from jsp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output). Personally, I use Freemarker, and its directive `<#ftl strip_whitespace=true>`, so I hope the former link is the jsp variant of that.