# jsp trimDirectiveWhitespaces rendering result bug

Tags: jsp, rendering, directive, trim, removing-whitespace

I use trim-directive-whitespaces option in web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

So I think that jsp result is nice.

But I found seeing bug that jsp result rendering.

for example.

here is part of sample jsp code.

(value1 : abcd, value2: efgh)

```
<div class="${value1} ${value2}"></div>
```

result I think: `<div class="abcd efgh"></div>`

actual result: `<div class="abcdefgh"></div>`

middle spaces are removed!!

I can understand.

How can I fix it as I thought?

Did I misunderstood?

please help me.

Comment: I see suggested solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208736/strip-whitespace-from-jsp-output    Using that solution, you would have     <div class="${value1}&nbsp;${value2}"></div>

Comment: If you are not familiar with it, then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: @rickz 
thank you to your guide. I thought that my question would work normally.
But when I thought about it, I started to think it was right to treat it as "& nsbp;" if it was absolutely necessary.